# web components Polymer.import() - support for composition?

Tags: polymer

I have successfully used [Polymer.import](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/helpers.html) to dynamically hydrate a UI with code like this run from within a JS module:

```
Polymer.import(['MyApp/Content/myMap.html'], function() {  // do some other work });
```

My new web component contains a mapping component and i see the tag is fully initialized and working within the main application page.

My problem lies with doing the same with more complex web components made up of other sub-components. e.g (code simplified for clarity):

```
<link rel="import" href="../lib/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="main-toolbar" attributes="">

    <link rel="import" href="./myTools.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./toolsetManager.html">   

    <template>

        <style>
            :host {
                /* Note: by default elements are always display:inline. */
            }

        </style>


        <div layout horizontal class="container">
            <div layout vertical center>
                <paper-icon-button icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
                <my-tools></my-tools>
            </div>
            <toolset-manager></toolset-manager>
        </div>
    </template>
```

my-tools and toolset-manager are 2 custom tags.
The toolset-manager tag is actually a composition of 2 other components.
In this case when i try the same import method on the main component file like this:

```
        Polymer.import(['MyApp/Content/custom/MainToolbar.html'], function() {
            // done
        });
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on
> 'Node': Nodes of type 'HTML' may not be inserted inside nodes of type
> '#document'.

I haven't been able to find any examples of Polymer.import() with composition so i'm wondering if its even supported?

I've actually been trying some tests on polymer core components that i know are composites with little success and the same error.

So i'm wondering if anyone else has an example code snippet where they have done this successfully?

Appreciate any tips!  thanks

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation and simplification of the problem down to a basic index.html page rather than an ASP Razor page (as was being used to serve the main content), i have been able to prove the Polymer.import with composition works just fine. My more complex element does now show correctly.

The problem  appears to be with the .import() not resolving the root application URL correctly which i think is something i need to resolve at the ASP/IIS level.

Answer (score 0):

Ok definitive answer this time.

**Polymer.import() is CASE sensitive!** The URL i was composing for the import had slightly different case. On matching exactly the load errors disappear.

I think i saw something similar in another polymer related post.